# Adding contents of object to list rather then parameter type?

Tags: c#, list, object

Hopefully I am describing this correctly and clear enough. I am trying to save multiple details entered by a user and save them to list. However the current way I am doing so is only saving the object type/name rather then the data. Below is my code how would I save the objects data rather then the name of the object?

```
Student stud = new Student();
stud.Enter_Student();
_studentList.Add(stud);
```

Enter Student

```
class Student : Person
{
    public string StudentId { get; private set; }
    public string Subject { get; private set; }

    //string[] _studentdb = new string[4];

    public Student()
    {
        StudentId = "abc123";
        Subject = "Building Subject";
    }

    public void Enter_Student()
    {
            this.Person_Prompt_Print(); //Prompts for user
            this.Address_Prompt_Print();
            this.Contact_Prompt_Print();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 18);
            Console.WriteLine("Student ID:");

            this.Enter_Person(); // Inputs from user
            this.Enter_Address();
            this.Enter_Contacts();
            StudentId = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 18);
    }
}
```

Date sample from person class

```
class Person
{

    Tidyup tidy = new Tidyup();

    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string Surname { get; private set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; private set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; private set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; private set; }
    public string Town { get; private set; }
    public string Postcode { get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string Telephone { get; private set; }



    public Person()
    {
        FirstName = "Name";
        Surname = "Surname";
        MiddleName = "Middle Name";
        AddressLine1 = "Address";
        AddressLine2 = "Address Ln2";
        Town = "Town";
        Postcode = "<xxx>/<xxx>";
        Email = "name@buildright.ac.uk";
        Telephone = "0800 0000000";
    }

    public void Person_Prompt_Print()
    {
        // Program Frame
        tidy.Line_Top();
        tidy.Line_Base();
        tidy.Sides_Left();
        tidy.Sides_Right();

        Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 2); //Prompts for user
        Console.WriteLine("FirstName:");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 4);
        Console.WriteLine("Surname:");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 6);
        Console.WriteLine("Middle Name:");
    }

    public void Address_Prompt_Print()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 8); //Prompts for user
        Console.WriteLine("House Number/Name:");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 10);
        Console.WriteLine("Street:");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 12);
        Console.WriteLine("Town:");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 14);
        Console.WriteLine("Post Code:");
    }

    public void Contact_Prompt_Print()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 16);
        Console.WriteLine("Email:");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 18);
        Console.WriteLine("Telephone:");
    }

    public void Enter_Person()
    {

        Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 2); // Inputs from user
        FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 4);
        Surname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 6);
        MiddleName = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void Enter_Address()
    {

        Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 8);  // Inputs from user
        AddressLine1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 10);
        AddressLine2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 12);
        Town = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 14);
        Postcode = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void Enter_Contacts()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 16);
        Email = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 18);
        Telephone = Console.ReadLine();
    }

} // End of Class
```

And finally I am printing out via a simple nested foreach loop

```
public void Print_all_student()
{
    Console.Clear();

    foreach (Student t in _studentList)
    {
        // print another list items.
        foreach (Student t1 in _studentList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("/" + t + "/" + t1);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

If anyone can help me understand what I am missing and how to access the data to print out I would be grateful. Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Why do you print a combination of 2 students? t and t1? Why do you print the class and not it's inner content? Also, what do you mean by "saving"? Do you have some kind of serialization or do you mean you put that information in your program's memory?

Comment: My bad explanation, all I am trying to print the inner content but unsure how to access that.

Comment: You can access an object members with "."... As devdigital said. `myStudent.FirstName`. Which is surprising, because you use it everywhere... like `this.FirstName` or `Console.WriteLine()`. One is a property and the other is a method, but both are members of a class.

Comment: It was stupidity on my part, feel very stupid now

Comment: Happens to the best of us. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of issues here, but in your `Console.WriteLine` call, you are only displaying the `Student` type, so the `ToString` method on the `Student` type will be invoked, which by default will display the type name.

You want to display the individual properties of the `Student` type, e.g.

```
foreach (Student student in studentList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student.FirstName);
    Console.WriteLine(student.Surname);
    // etc
}
```

Remember that `Student` derives from `Person`, so all of the public properties are accessible from a `Student` reference, because `Student` is a `Person`.

Also:

1. You have a redundant loop - you only need one loop which enumerates the `studentList`
2. There is a real mixture of concerns here. Your `Student` and `Person` types should not be concerned with UI (i.e. anything to do with `Console` calls)
3. Stick with PascalCase (aka UpperCamelCase) for your method names, no underscores

Comment: Thank you for this, one question about your third point  about using PascalCase the _ method names was suggested by resharper which I have installed which I assumed was showing me correct practice, I was naming them before as you have suggested, is this the known standard?

Comment: It would depend on your particular ReSharper configuration, but the best standards to follow would be those of StyleCop (http://stylecop.codeplex.com/). StyleCop comes with a plugin for ReSharper which should work depending on the version of ReSharper you're running.

Comment: Thank you that link  and your support I have installed the extension to my copy resharper, hopefully at least my method name will be correct now.

Comment: Actually I've just looked and surprisingly method naming is not a StyleCop rule, but rather is enforced by ReSharper by default, so somewhere you must have changed the default ReSharper settings.